# Can't find d.rast.edit in my GRASS modules

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I'm trying to manually edit a raster by using the GRASS tool d.rast.edit as I've seen it's worked for other users. However, even though I have the rest of the GRASS tools, I can't seem to find the module corresponding to d.rast.edit. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm using QGIS 3.28, maybe it's not compatible? Do I need to install an extension?

Comment: Are you trying to use it from the QGIS processing toolbox or the Grass GUI?

Answer (score 0):

The [display](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/display.html) (d.*) commands belong to the GRASS GIS graphical user interface. There are no wrappers provided in QGIS since it uses its own display system. To use d.* commands you may use GRASS GIS and its graphical user interface directly.